# Commit message file missing in commit-msg hook

Tags: bash, git, githooks, pre-commit-hook, commit-message

I'm trying to write a commit-msg hook to format my commit messages to wrap at a maximum column width:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

format_max_column_width() {
  MAX_LINE_LENGTH_CHARS=50

  cat "$1" | grep -v "^Bug: |^Change-Id: |^Signed-off-by: |^CC: " > body
  cat "$1" | grep "^Bug: |^Change-Id: |^Signed-off-by: |^CC: " > footer
  fmt -w "$MAX_LINE_LENGTH_CHARS" body > body
  cat body > "$1"
  cat footer >> "$1"
  rm body footer
}

format_max_column_width
```

For some reason, when I make a commit, I get the following errors because $1 seems to be empty.

```
cat: '': No such file or directory
cat: '': No such file or directory
.git/hooks/commit-msg: line 9: : No such file or directory
.git/hooks/commit-msg: line 10: : No such file or directory
```

Moreover, if I just `echo $1`, nothing will be printed, confirming this theory. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a shell function `$1` means "the first parameter to **the function**", not to the script. You need to pass the first script parameter further to the function:

```
format_max_column_width "$1"
```